# How to apply OAuth2 in "web service" scenario?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

How would I apply OAuth2 in the following scenario:

I have an app that has to connect to an external service that used OAuth2 authentication. The resource owner is not the user of the app, but the app itself (so there is just one account that should be used by all users of the app). In this case, we can not show the user a login screen to connect to the external service. How do I apply OAuth2 in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Form your explanation it appears you should use the [client_credentials](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/) grant_type.

Or as you tagged with "Google" perhaps use the [OAuth2ServiceAccount](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)